# Integrating a vector field along the edge of a surface

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

At it for over a day now, must concede.

Lets have a vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(xz,yz+x^2yz+y^3z+yz^5,2z^4)$ with the surface $\Sigma$ given as $(x^2+y^2+z^4)e^{y^2}=1, x\geq 0$ oriented so its normal at the point $(1,0,0)$ is $\vec{N} = (1,0,0)$.

Calculate the work of this vector field along the edge of $\Sigma$, which is oriented with respect to $\Sigma$'s orientation.

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Comment: Well I went over the basics. Thought about $\int_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{A}d\vec{r}=\iint_{\Sigma}rot(\vec{A})dP$

But got stuck at how to write this surface into two parameters...just fully stuck

Comment: Hint for the parameterization: use $y$ and $z$ as parameters in $(y, z) \mapsto (X(y,z), y, z)$, where $X(y, z) = \sqrt{\frac{1 - (y^2 + z^4) e^{y^2}}{e^{y^2}}}$, and (because you were told that $x \ge 0$, you choose the nonnnegative square root. Finding the domain for $y$ and $z$ remains a challenge for *you* to address.

Comment: @KatptonLiamfuppinshire I'm certainly not begging for up or even (!) down-votes, but I am curious: was my answer below useful, useless, or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I obviously think this is right, but I'm a little bit nervous that I might be doing something stupid. Still, nothing ventured... Let me know what you think.

With the notation as in the question,
$$ \partial \Sigma = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in {\mathbb R^3}\mid (x^2 + y^2 + z^4) e^{y^2} = 1, x = 0\right\}.$$

Therefore we want to evaluate the integral

$$ I= \int _{\partial\Sigma} (yz + y^3 z + yz^5 ) \,dy + 2 z^4 \,dz.  $$

There are no $x$ terms, because $x=0$ identically on $\partial \Sigma$. That being the case, the $x$ value is irrelevant, and we can consider this as a problem of integration in $\mathbb R^2$, rather than in $\mathbb R^3$.

Namely, the 'path' $\partial \Sigma$ is also the boundary of $$S = \left\{ (x,y,z) \mid (y^2 + z^4) e^{y^2} \le 1, x = 0\right\},$$
and by Green/Stokes, one has that

$$ I = - \int_S (y + y^3 + 5yz^4)\, dy\wedge dz,  $$
where one can view the latter as an integral in the $x=0$ a.k.a. $y/z$ plane.

So consider the double integral  (no $x$'s) as an iterated integral, and do the $y$ integral first (i.e., hold $z$ constant): we want to evaluate ($z$ fixed)
$$J_z = \int_{y^2 - e^{-y^2} \le -z^4} f(y,z) \, dy, $$
where $f(y,z) = (y +y^3 + 5yz^4)$.

Now, the domain of integration in $J_z$ is symmetric about  $y=0$. On the other hand $y\mapsto f(y,z)$ is an odd function. Therefore $J_z = 0$, and $I=0$ also.